# ligthweight draggable lock in parent width and height area

Tags: javascript, jquery

Found a lightway draggable function. How can I lock the draggable black block in parent area? Do i need to do a width and height to limit black block area?

online sample http://jsfiddle.net/zqYZG/

```
.drag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.box{
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

jQuery

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.draggable = function(options) {
        var $handle = this,
            $draggable = this;

        options = $.extend({}, {
            handle: null,
            cursor: 'move'
        }, options);

        if( options.handle ) {
            $handle = $(options.handle);
        }

        $handle
            .css('cursor', options.cursor)
            .on("mousedown", function(e) {
                var x = $draggable.offset().left - e.pageX,
                    y = $draggable.offset().top - e.pageY,a
                    z = $draggable.css('z-index');

                $draggable.css('z-index', 100000);

                $(document.documentElement)
                    .on('mousemove.draggable', function(e) {
                        $draggable.offset({
                            left: x + e.pageX,
                             top: y + e.pageY
                        });
                    })
                    .one('mouseup', function() {
                        $(this).off('mousemove.draggable');
                        $draggable.css('z-index', z);
                    });

                // disable selection
                e.preventDefault();
            });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.drag').draggable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it, using the `getBoundingClientRect()` function: [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8g4R/4/)

This just constrains the `l` and `t` variables from your original code, to be within the parent node's dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

See [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option!

use :

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```